# 2D Array Memory Mapping C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a 2d array and a pointer which points to its first element:

```
int s[100][100];
int* p;
```

after reading some value and saving in s:

```
p=&s[0][0]
```

Well, now I want to print s elements, by accessing it through p:

```
for (x = 0; x<m; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y<n; y++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(p + sizeof(int)*x*n + y));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

which m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns.
But... It gives me wrong answer.
I guess the expression 'p + sizeof(int)*x*n + y' is causing the problem. Please help me correct it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `sizeof(int)` - pointer arithmetic takes care of element size automatically - change:

```
p + sizeof(int)*x*n + y
```

to:

```
p + x*n + y
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of errors. The first one was pointed out by Paul K. The second one is that you will have to use:

```
    printf("%d ", *(p + x*100 + y));
```

instead of

```
    printf("%d ", *(p + x*n + y));
```

Otherwise, you will be picking up the numbers from the wrong row.